# Google Font has a different appearance in Gmail on Mobile and Desktop than what it really is

Tags: html, css, fonts, gmail, google-fonts

Why does google font appear different in Website, Gmail App on Phone and Gmail on desktop? I am using [Merienda One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merienda+One?preview.text=Lovely&preview.text_type=custom#glyphs) font and to my surprise it's not same everywhere. I am sure this would be issue with different fonts or all fonts but let's talk about this one now as a reference as I am using it.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda+One&display=swap");
      .mail-head {
        border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: "Merienda One", cursive;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mail-head">Lovely</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actual Font on Google Fonts

[image]

1. On Gmail Desktop

[image]

2. On Gmail Android

[image]

I want to fix this. I want the original appearance of the font everywhere. What is the solution?

Comment: Try setting the fallback option from cursive to say serif and see what happens. Ie I don’t think the first choice font looks different on different systems, they just aren’t picking it up.

Comment: @AHaworth serif changes it to default font. Not working :(

Comment: @AHaworth also as you said that they aren't picking it up I am just wondering why one Google product can't pick another Google product!

Comment: Quite, what that is proving is that at least some of the email systems are not prepared to deal with all external fonts. You probably need to read up about each system that is of interest to see what it will allow, but you’ll probably need a sensible fallback for some.

Comment: If there is no quick fix for this issue I will better switch to using image instead.

Comment: Well, I for one don’t allow images to be shown on received emails so I’d advise using images only for fun/visual interest, not for conveying any information.

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry? What's "I for one"? Did you mean iPhone? Also, I will use image only for logo. Nothing else.

Comment: No, sorry! I meant that I (=me) don't allow images to be shown on incoming emails (unless I choose to see them on an individual basis).,

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. The heading you see in the images given in the question is the Logo of the app. Hence, I can use image for just this 1 thing. However, if any mail or OS doesn't allow image to be shown that would not be a great thing to look at. Therefore, I wanted to use text even for the logo as my app's logo is created using simple text and font and no fancy image. But this issue, this shit completely changes the identity of the brand!